# QOpenGLFunctions.glDrawElements only works with VoidPtr(0)?

Tags: python, opengl, null, pyside2, qopenglfunctions

I have been trying to draw elements using Qt5's `QOpenGLFunctions` and `QOpenGLExtraFunctions` classes, and I've had quite a few issues with argument types (but I will leave other issues out of this particular question). This question pertains to the use of `glDrawElements`, which is (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QOpenGLFunctions.glDrawElements)) a "Convenience function that calls glDrawElements(mode, count, type, indices)." Indices in this case (from [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/glDrawElements.xhtml)):

> Specifies a byte offset (cast to a pointer type) into the buffer bound
>   to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER to start reading indices from. If no buffer
>   is bound, specifies a pointer to the location where the indices are
>   stored.

In my case, I have no offset to the indices I want to access (0). I was under the belief that `None` would be Python's equivalent to a null pointer here, but I've so far *only* had success if I pass in `shiboken2.shiboken2.VoidPtr(0)`, and I don't entirely understand why, nor how to (if at all possible) do this in a more "pythonic" way.

I am using Python3.8, PySide2, and OpenGL4.1 (core).